# How to display a special character with Qt on Android

Tags: android, qt, qml

I'm trying to use the *warning* (⚠, `\u26A0`) [Unicode character](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/2000-2FFF) in a Qt QML application (using Qt 5.6), but it is not printed to the screen when I deploy the application to the Android device emulator. I use a `Text` to display it.

```
Text {
  text: "How are you feeling? *\u26A0**⚠*"
}
```

Is there some kind of limitation?

Comment: Make sure that the qml file is Utf-8 encoded, and that the fonts that the emulator uses have that character.

Comment: The QML file is utf8-encoded. Qt Quick Text example prints the warning character when deployed to Windows and does not when deployed to the device emulator.

Comment: Emojis did not work until Qt 5.7 (see https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35156) This seems to be fixed in 5.7. Have you tried different fonts/symbols?

Comment: @Felix That's exactly the problem. I was using QT 5.6.1 btw, and not 5.7 as I thought. I update my question accordingly.

Comment: Well in that case, the solution is to update to 5.7. I don't know of any other way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some unicode symbols are not supported by Qt on Android prior 5.7. See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-35156

With Qt 5.7 this seems to be fixed. As far as I know, updating to 5.7 is the only solution to get these symbols work with Qt on Android

Answer (score 0):

Just like Kuba Ober pointed out, make sure that the qml file is Utf-8 encoded. That said, the following should just work:

```
Text {
  text: "How are you feeling? ⚠"
}
```

An image showing the result:
[image]

Comment: Is it running on an Android device ?